# Lower semi-continuous functions coinciding on a dense subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f$ and $h$ be two lower semi-continuous functions from a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$. If $f$ and $h$ coincide in a dense subset of $X$,
do $f$ and $h$ coincide on the whole space $X$?.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, take a continuous function, and lessen the value of the function at a single point (well, a single non-isolated point!).

Comment: An example that is more extreme in certain ways is the additive inverse of the [Thomae function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) --- lower semicontinuous, and coincides with the zero function on a dense set, and differs from  the zero function a dense set.

Comment: Are there supplementaires conditions assure the coinciding of two lower semicontinuous functions?

Comment: @Ilyes Not really. As you can see from the example above, there isn't much control over individual function values. With continuous functions, the function values around the point will force the value of the function. With lower semicontinuity, the function values around the point merely enforce an upper bound on the function value; the function value at the point is free to be as low as it wants.